# POST method posts partial data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I have a form in my app that uses ajax to update. I have 3 dropdownLists initially but after ajax call number increases. Here is my form

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'schedule-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

    <p class="help-block">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'class_id',$classes); ?>

       <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'day_id',$days,array('selected'=>$i)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model,'teacher_id',$days); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::textField('', '',array('id'=>'search-field')); ?>




    <div  id="copy1">



    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit',
            'type'=>'primary',
            'label'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save',
        )); ?>
    </div>

<?php  $this->endWidget(); ?>
        <?php $url=Ccontroller::createUrl('schedule/ajaxSchedule');  Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('#search-field').keyup(function(){
$.ajax(
        {
        url:'".$url."',
        data:{ajaxdata:$(this).val()},
        success:function(data){
        $('#copy1').empty();
        $('#copy1').html(data);
        },

        }
        );
});
");
?>
```

When I type inm textfield it makes an ajax call. Ajax call is perfect and returns the needed data. In my returned data I have some repeated widgets. They are displayed well no issue there. But when I submit the form I only get results from last widgets. Even initial dropDowns are also not posted, I mean their results are not posted. What i am doing wrong?

Here is my ajax retuned code.

```
<?php

for($i=0;$i<$numberOfperiods;$i++ ){
?>
 <div class="row copy">
       <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('Schedule','subject_id[]',$courses,array('id'=>'subject_is'.$i)); ?>
       <?php $config1=array('model' => $model,
                   'attribute'=>'start_time[]','htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'start_time'.$i));
       $this->widget(
               'bootstrap.widgets.TbTimePicker', $config1
       );
       ?>
         <?php $config=array('model' => $model,
                   'attribute'=>'end_time[]','htmlOptions'=>array('id'=>'end_time'.$i));
       $this->widget(
               'bootstrap.widgets.TbTimePicker', $config
       );
       ?>


    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

The loop works well. Suppose i have numberOfperiods =6 so 6 widgets will be displayed. But when i submit then the results of only last widgets are submitted.

Comment: can you add the rendered html of the inputs

Comment: i have checked it and increased it from 8M to 20M but still same results. And I also have sent more data than that. But i am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your web server config. If you're using Apache you should check `post_max_size` (iirc)

Comment: i have checked it and increased it from 8M to 20M but still same results. And I also have sent more data than that. But i am not sure why this is happening.